# Android MathView Overflows Width Of Screen

Tags: android

When using Mathview show math, my webview overflows width. Although i'm using "autobreak" in underneath code. It not working. This is my code in class MathJaxWebview in Mathview lib, and settext for webview myWebview.setText(content); :

```js
 

           public void setText(final String text) {
               loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",
            "<head>" +
                    "<style>" +
                    "img{max-width:100%}\r\n" +
                    "audio{background:#2888e1;padding:10px;height: 47px;}" +
                    "</style>" +
                    "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
                   "MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +
                    "              showMathMenu: false,\n" +
                    "                messageStyle: \"none\",\n" +
                    "                     SVG: {\n" +
                    "                          scale: 120,\n" +
                    "                          linebreaks: {\n" +
                    "                              automatic: true\n" +
                    "                          }\n" +
                    "                     },\n" +
                    "                     \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +
                    "                      CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +
                    "            tex2jax: {\n" +
                    "                   inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], [\"\\\\(\",\"\\\\)\"] ]\n" +
                    "            }\n" +
                    "            });" +
                    "MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {    document.getElementById(\"hide_page\").style.visibility = \"\";  });" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script>" +
                    "" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body style=\"text-align:justify\">" +
                    text +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
}
```

**And my String**

[example content math this link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceFQqGktnS?indent=2)

**Please help me, thank all bro**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving this code:

```
`"              showMathMenu: false,\n" +
                    "                messageStyle: \"none\",\n" +
                    "                     SVG: {\n" +
                    "                          scale: 120,\n" +
                    "                          linebreaks: {\n" +
                    "                              automatic: true\n" +
                    "                          }\n" +
                    "                     },\n" +
                    "                     \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +
                    "                      CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +`
```

to below `"            tex2jax: {\n" +...`.

The new code:

```
    public void setText(final String text) {
        loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",
                "<head>" +
                        "<meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi'/>"+
                        "<style>" +
                        "img{max-width:100%}\r\n" +
                        "audio{background:#2888e1;padding:10px;height: 47px;}" +
                        "</style>" +
                        "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
                        "MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +

                        "            tex2jax: {\n" +
                        "                   inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], [\"\\\\(\",\"\\\\)\"] ]\n" +
                        "            },\n" +
                        "              showMathMenu: false,\n" +
                        "                messageStyle: \"none\",\n" +
                        "                     SVG: {\n" +
                        "                          scale: 120,\n" +
                        "                          linebreaks: {\n" +
                        "                              automatic: true\n" +
                        "                          }\n" +
                        "                     },\n" +
                        "                     \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +
                        "                      CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },\n" +
                        "            });" +
                        "MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {    document.getElementById(\"hide_page\").style.visibility = \"\";  });" +
                        "</script>" +
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script>" +
                        "" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body style=\"text-align:justify\">" +
                        text +
                        "</body>" +
                        "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    }
```